# Manipulating Model data in controller before sending to View - Laravel

Tags: laravel, view

I am receiving some data from my model and would like to manipulate it before sending to one of my views.  The view is mainly just a javascript datagrid that will display the incoming JSON response as-is, so cannot re-format anything in the view.

My current response from the model, when sent to the view looks like this:

```
{
  "first_name": "Joe",
  "last_name": "Jackson",
  "nickname": "JJ",
  "salutation": "Mr",
  "city": "Oakville",
  "country": "Newland",
  "orders": "12",
  "total": "34600.00"
}
```

The response I would like to send to the view, needs to be reformatted in way that the view can use and display directly, **without any further manipulation** being done in the view e.g:

```
{
  "Client": "Mr Joe Jackson<br>Oakville, Newland",
  "Orders": "12 Orders<br>Total Sales: $34600.00"
}
```

I can write a function to re-format the data, but where should I place this function and how should I access it?

FYI, Im not using blade as this is primarily for a single page JS app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a function into a Model and use it from controller, something like:

```
Client:: getFormattedData($id);
```

And in a model:

```
public function getFormattedData($id)
{
    ....
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexey. So do I perform the query in the controller first, and then pass on the result from the into `Client::getFormattedData($queryResults);` method as a parameter? Or would I use `Client::getFormattedData()` to perform the actual query?

Comment: You use `Client:: getFormattedData($id);` in a controller to perfom a query. `getFormattedData($id);` is a function in Model.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!